# Compiling OpenSSL with Dynamic Zlib in Windows

Tags: c++, openssl, zlib

I am trying to create a 32-bit dynamic build of OpenSSL on Windows. I have also built a 32-bit dynamic version of Zlib  on Windows. There is not a static version available in my Zlib directories.

Everywhere I've read says that's all that is needed; however, when I compile Zlib does not appear as a dependency inside library. How can I get OpenSSL to **dynamically** link Zlib?

Configuration invocation:

`perl Configure threads shared zlib-dynamic --prefix=C:\local\windows\vc11\32\openssl --with-zlib-lib=C:\local\windows\vc11\32\zlib\lib\zlibd.lib --with-zlib-include=C:\local\windows\vc11\32\zlib\include no-rc5 no-idea no-ssl2 -D_REENTRANT debug-VC-WIN32`

Output:

```
Configuring for debug-VC-WIN32
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-idea         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_IDEA (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [option]   OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-ssl2         [option]   OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
IsMK1MF=1
CC            =cl
CFLAG         =-DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -D_REENTRANT -W3 -Gs0 -GF -Gy -Zi -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
EX_LIBS       =
CPUID_OBJ     =x86cpuid.o
BN_ASM        =bn-586.o co-586.o x86-mont.o x86-gf2m.o
DES_ENC       =des-586.o crypt586.o
AES_ENC       =aes-586.o vpaes-x86.o aesni-x86.o
BF_ENC        =bf-586.o
CAST_ENC      =c_enc.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4-586.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5-586.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-586.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-586.o sha256-586.o sha512-586.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=rmd-586.o
CMLL_ENC      =cmll-x86.o
MODES_OBJ     =ghash-x86.o
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =true
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_INDEX mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefined

Configured for debug-VC-WIN32.
```

Command: `ms\do_nasm.bat`

Output:

```
C:\Source\OpenSsl\openssl-1.0.1j>perl util\mkfiles.pl  1>MINFO 

C:\Source\OpenSsl\openssl-1.0.1j>perl util\mk1mf.pl dll nasm VC-WIN32  1>ms\ntdll.mak 
     ...
Link Ret:$(BIN_D)\$(E_EXE).exe: $(E_OBJ) $(LIBS_DEP)
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) /out:$(BIN_D)\$(E_EXE).exe @<<
    $(APP_EX_OBJ) $(E_OBJ) $(L_LIBS) $(EX_LIBS)
<<
    IF EXIST $@.manifest mt -nologo -manifest $@.manifest -outputresource:$@;1


#       Post zlib_opt:2
#       Post zlib_lib:C:\local\windows\vc11\32\zlib\lib\zlibd.lib
```

Dumpbins:

```
Dump of file libeay32.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following imports:

    WS2_32.dll
              100B620C Import Address Table
              100EEB04 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      Ordinal    20
                      Ordinal    17
                      Ordinal   116
                      Ordinal   115
                      Ordinal    55
                      Ordinal    52
                      Ordinal    15
                      Ordinal    14
                      Ordinal    13
                      Ordinal     7
                      Ordinal    10
                      Ordinal     2
                      Ordinal     1
                      Ordinal    23
                      Ordinal    21
                      Ordinal     9
                      Ordinal     8
                      Ordinal     4
                      Ordinal   111
                      Ordinal   112
                      Ordinal    22
                      Ordinal    19
                      Ordinal    16
                      Ordinal     3

    GDI32.dll
              100B6010 Import Address Table
              100EE908 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  2C9 SelectObject
                  1EB GetDeviceCaps
                  1C7 GetBitmapBits
                  105 DeleteObject
                  102 DeleteDC
                   32 CreateDCA
                   31 CreateCompatibleDC
                   30 CreateCompatibleBitmap
                   13 BitBlt
                  21B GetObjectA

    ADVAPI32.dll
              100B6000 Import Address Table
              100EE8F8 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  2AA RegisterEventSourceA
                   EB DeregisterEventSource
                  2BA ReportEventA

    USER32.dll
              100B61F8 Import Address Table
              100EEAF0 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  138 GetDesktopWindow
                  244 MessageBoxA
                  1B7 GetUserObjectInformationW
                  192 GetProcessWindowStation

    MSVCR110.dll
              100B60AC Import Address Table
              100EE9A4 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  190 __clean_type_info_names_internal
                  422 _onexit
                  469 _snprintf
                  279 _exit
                  69C wcsstr
                  1B6 __iob_func
                  67A vfprintf
                  50A _vsnprintf
                  639 raise
                  63C realloc
                  61D malloc
                  5E4 free
                  628 memcpy
                  37A _localtime64
                  4CA _time64
                  62C memset
                  2EF _gmtime64
                  49A _stricmp
                  4A4 _strnicmp
                  26D _errno
                  65D strncpy
                  626 memchr
                  62A memmove
                  43B _read
                  588 _write
                  5FE isdigit
                  613 isxdigit
                  5DC fprintf
                  5BF atoi
                  648 sprintf
                  663 strstr
                  5DF fputs
                  5CF fclose
                  5D0 feof
                  5D1 ferror
                  5D2 fflush
                  5D5 fgets
                  287 _fileno
                  5DA fopen
                  5E2 fread
                  5EA fseek
                  5EC ftell
                  5EF fwrite
                  56D _wfopen
                  466 _setmode
                  650 strchr
                  62E perror
                  2B4 _ftime64
                  637 qsort
                  651 strcmp
                  27F _fdopen
                  5F4 getenv
                  235 _chmod
                  423 _open
                  490 _stat64i32
                  656 strerror
                  604 isspace
                  5FB isalnum
                  674 tolower
                  65C strncmp
                  605 isupper
                  668 strtoul
                  661 strrchr
                  64C sscanf
                  5CC exit
                  667 strtol
                  645 signal
                  2D6 _getch
                  630 printf
                  24B _crt_debugger_hook
                  1AA __crtUnhandledException
                  1A9 __crtTerminateProcess
                  270 _except_handler4_common
                  173 __CppXcptFilter
                  215 _amsg_exit
                  38D _malloc_crt
                  2FE _initterm
                  2FF _initterm_e
                  37C _lock
                  4E6 _unlock
                  22B _calloc_crt
                  1AC __dllonexit

    KERNEL32.dll
              100B603C Import Address Table
              100EE934 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  1B8 FreeLibrary
                   8E CloseHandle
                  199 FindNextFileA
                  188 FindFirstFileA
                  3C0 LoadLibraryA
                  321 GetVersion
                  228 GetCurrentThreadId
                  26A GetLastError
                  257 GetFileType
                  2DD GetStdHandle
                  517 SetLastError
                  3EC MultiByteToWideChar
                  43C QueryPerformanceCounter
                  224 GetCurrentProcessId
                  310 GetTickCount
                  322 GetVersionExA
                  341 GlobalMemoryStatus
                  1AC FlushConsoleInputBuffer
                  383 IsDebuggerPresent
                  13C EncodePointer
                  388 IsProcessorFeaturePresent
                  117 DecodePointer
                  2F4 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
                  184 FindClose
                  2B5 GetProcAddress
                  27E GetModuleHandleA
                  16D ExitProcess

  Summary

        9000 .data
       54000 .rdata
        B000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       B5000 .text

Dump of file ssleay32.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following imports:

    LIBEAY32.dll
              1002E030 Import Address Table
              10035B9C Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      Ordinal   903
                      Ordinal   188
                      Ordinal   181
                      Ordinal  3245
                      Ordinal    66
                      Ordinal    52
                      Ordinal   111
                      Ordinal   110
                      Ordinal   151
                      Ordinal   123
                      Ordinal   118
                      Ordinal   120
                      Ordinal   128
                      Ordinal   165
                      Ordinal    32
                      Ordinal   490
                      Ordinal  2760
                      Ordinal   495
                      Ordinal   498
                      Ordinal  4540
                      Ordinal   202
                      Ordinal   203
                      Ordinal   201
                      Ordinal   219
                      Ordinal   252
                      Ordinal   222
                      Ordinal  3837
                      Ordinal  3844
                      Ordinal  3896
                      Ordinal  3899
                      Ordinal  2630
                      Ordinal  2821
                      Ordinal  3883
                      Ordinal  3109
                      Ordinal   269
                      Ordinal  2936
                      Ordinal  2894
                      Ordinal   276
                      Ordinal   274
                      Ordinal   289
                      Ordinal   290
                      Ordinal   961
                      Ordinal   256
                      Ordinal  3315
                      Ordinal  2927
                      Ordinal   285
                      Ordinal   281
                      Ordinal  4119
                      Ordinal  4430
                      Ordinal  4233
                      Ordinal  4474
                      Ordinal  4369
                      Ordinal  4245
                      Ordinal  1070
                      Ordinal  4488
                      Ordinal  3695
                      Ordinal  3570
                      Ordinal  2924
                      Ordinal  2929
                      Ordinal  3010
                      Ordinal  3178
                      Ordinal  2578
                      Ordinal  3663
                      Ordinal  3422
                      Ordinal  3729
                      Ordinal  3575
                      Ordinal  3512
                      Ordinal  3608
                      Ordinal  3459
                      Ordinal  3480
                      Ordinal  3550
                      Ordinal  3666
                      Ordinal  3644
                      Ordinal   866
                      Ordinal   641
                      Ordinal   754
                      Ordinal   654
                      Ordinal   635
                      Ordinal  2747
                      Ordinal  2784
                      Ordinal  2572
                      Ordinal   964
                      Ordinal   965
                      Ordinal  2206
                      Ordinal  2201
                      Ordinal  3489
                      Ordinal   907
                      Ordinal   904
                      Ordinal   176
                      Ordinal    87
                      Ordinal   486
                      Ordinal   497
                      Ordinal   493
                      Ordinal   484
                      Ordinal   205
                      Ordinal   206
                      Ordinal   216
                      Ordinal   363
                      Ordinal  2712
                      Ordinal  2925
                      Ordinal  3165
                      Ordinal   268
                      Ordinal   333
                      Ordinal   316
                      Ordinal   282
                      Ordinal  4125
                      Ordinal  4262
                      Ordinal  4164
                      Ordinal  1071
                      Ordinal  2877
                      Ordinal  3711
                      Ordinal  3682
                      Ordinal  3719
                      Ordinal   577
                      Ordinal   763
                      Ordinal   572
                      Ordinal   464
                      Ordinal  4046
                      Ordinal   481
                      Ordinal  3528
                      Ordinal  3418
                      Ordinal  3244
                      Ordinal  1096
                      Ordinal  1097
                      Ordinal    78
                      Ordinal   109
                      Ordinal    95
                      Ordinal  3816
                      Ordinal  3873
                      Ordinal  3836
                      Ordinal  3888
                      Ordinal  3891
                      Ordinal  3874
                      Ordinal  2589
                      Ordinal  2915
                      Ordinal   323
                      Ordinal  3906
                      Ordinal  1144
                      Ordinal  1145
                      Ordinal  3823
                      Ordinal  3846
                      Ordinal    89
                      Ordinal  2292
                      Ordinal  1081
                      Ordinal   187
                      Ordinal   623
                      Ordinal   622
                      Ordinal   857
                      Ordinal   679
                      Ordinal  3857
                      Ordinal   267
                      Ordinal   503
                      Ordinal  1012
                      Ordinal  3631
                      Ordinal  3479
                      Ordinal  3664
                      Ordinal  3737
                      Ordinal  3633
                      Ordinal  3675
                      Ordinal   341
                      Ordinal  1011
                      Ordinal  3067
                      Ordinal   266
                      Ordinal   264
                      Ordinal   912
                      Ordinal  3312
                      Ordinal  3313
                      Ordinal   541
                      Ordinal  3925
                      Ordinal  3922
                      Ordinal  3124
                      Ordinal  2702
                      Ordinal  2898
                      Ordinal  1202
                      Ordinal  4144
                      Ordinal  4372
                      Ordinal  3782
                      Ordinal  2400
                      Ordinal  4174
                      Ordinal  3866
                      Ordinal   313
                      Ordinal  3724
                      Ordinal  3767
                      Ordinal  3758
                      Ordinal  3704
                      Ordinal  3647
                      Ordinal  3365
                      Ordinal  3766
                      Ordinal  3460
                      Ordinal  4114
                      Ordinal  3783
                      Ordinal  3454
                      Ordinal  3394
                      Ordinal  3754
                      Ordinal  1655
                      Ordinal   914
                      Ordinal  1041
                      Ordinal  1027
                      Ordinal  1025
                      Ordinal  1004
                      Ordinal  1007
                      Ordinal  1005
                      Ordinal  3826
                      Ordinal    53
                      Ordinal    85
                      Ordinal    67
                      Ordinal    65
                      Ordinal    74
                      Ordinal    98
                      Ordinal    58
                      Ordinal   892
                      Ordinal   890
                      Ordinal   897
                      Ordinal  2257
                      Ordinal   248
                      Ordinal   364
                      Ordinal  4331
                      Ordinal  4513
                      Ordinal  1010
                      Ordinal   629
                      Ordinal   626
                      Ordinal   628
                      Ordinal   630
                      Ordinal  3437
                      Ordinal  3527
                      Ordinal  3378
                      Ordinal  3610
                      Ordinal  3414
                      Ordinal  3495
                      Ordinal  3399
                      Ordinal  3559
                      Ordinal   575
                      Ordinal   636
                      Ordinal  2051
                      Ordinal  2478
                      Ordinal   246
                      Ordinal  3657
                      Ordinal  3396
                      Ordinal   911
                      Ordinal    93
                      Ordinal  1100
                      Ordinal  1023
                      Ordinal  2524
                      Ordinal  3505
                      Ordinal  3595
                      Ordinal   657
                      Ordinal   401
                      Ordinal   891
                      Ordinal   887
                      Ordinal   889
                      Ordinal  4045
                      Ordinal  2475
                      Ordinal   368
                      Ordinal   370
                      Ordinal   367
                      Ordinal   369
                      Ordinal  1671
                      Ordinal   189
                      Ordinal  1147
                      Ordinal   314
                      Ordinal   315
                      Ordinal  4383
                      Ordinal  4320
                      Ordinal   956
                      Ordinal   750
                      Ordinal  3205
                      Ordinal   279
                      Ordinal   283
                      Ordinal   748
                      Ordinal   280
                      Ordinal   774
                      Ordinal   751
                      Ordinal  2181
                      Ordinal  1959
                      Ordinal   400
                      Ordinal   399
                      Ordinal  3513
                      Ordinal   716
                      Ordinal   822
                      Ordinal   718
                      Ordinal   824
                      Ordinal     8
                      Ordinal     7
                      Ordinal  3700
                      Ordinal  3623
                      Ordinal    37
                      Ordinal    35
                      Ordinal   703
                      Ordinal  1091
                      Ordinal    88
                      Ordinal  2426
                      Ordinal    86
                      Ordinal   680
                      Ordinal  1101
                      Ordinal   299
                      Ordinal   304
                      Ordinal   329
                      Ordinal   325
                      Ordinal   959
                      Ordinal  4601
                      Ordinal  3155
                      Ordinal  2996
                      Ordinal  4615
                      Ordinal  4637
                      Ordinal  4656
                      Ordinal  3795
                      Ordinal  3807
                      Ordinal  3914
                      Ordinal   292
                      Ordinal   293
                      Ordinal  2252
                      Ordinal    91
                      Ordinal   955
                      Ordinal   225
                      Ordinal   247
                      Ordinal   125
                      Ordinal   129
                      Ordinal  4572
                      Ordinal  4580
                      Ordinal  4576
                      Ordinal  4570
                      Ordinal  4578
                      Ordinal  4582
                      Ordinal  4573
                      Ordinal  4577
                      Ordinal  4581
                      Ordinal  4575
                      Ordinal  4584
                      Ordinal   910
                      Ordinal   909
                      Ordinal   905
                      Ordinal  2411
                      Ordinal  1653
                      Ordinal  1654
                      Ordinal   170
                      Ordinal  3239
                      Ordinal   168
                      Ordinal   167
                      Ordinal  3314
                      Ordinal   169

    MSVCR110.dll
              1002E584 Import Address Table
              100360F0 Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  173 __CppXcptFilter
                  215 _amsg_exit
                  5E4 free
                  38D _malloc_crt
                  2FE _initterm
                  2FF _initterm_e
                  24B _crt_debugger_hook
                  1AA __crtUnhandledException
                  1A9 __crtTerminateProcess
                  37C _lock
                  4E6 _unlock
                  22B _calloc_crt
                  1AC __dllonexit
                  422 _onexit
                  190 __clean_type_info_names_internal
                  270 _except_handler4_common
                  26D _errno
                  650 strchr
                  2B4 _ftime64
                  65C strncmp
                  62C memset
                  628 memcpy
                  65D strncpy
                  62A memmove
                  4CA _time64
                  5DC fprintf
                  1B6 __iob_func
                  5B5 abort

    KERNEL32.dll
              1002E000 Import Address Table
              10035B6C Import Name Table
                     0 time date stamp
                     0 Index of first forwarder reference

                  26A GetLastError
                  388 IsProcessorFeaturePresent
                  13C EncodePointer
                  117 DecodePointer
                  383 IsDebuggerPresent
                  43C QueryPerformanceCounter
                  224 GetCurrentProcessId
                  228 GetCurrentThreadId
                  2F4 GetSystemTimeAsFileTime
                  12E DisableThreadLibraryCalls
                  517 SetLastError

  Summary

        4000 .data
        B000 .rdata
        3000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       2D000 .text
```

Comment: It is hard to see what happened with one bit of information "it didn't work". One would need to look at both configure logs and make logs.

Comment: Can you try to build OpenSSL without zlib? If you can build it successfully, we can detect the problem with zlib.

Comment: My note to build OpenSSL: http://tuan.nguoianphu.com/OpenSSL_compile_for_Linux_Solaris_Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compiling with Dynamic Zlib in Windows...

When you statically link against zlib or use options like `no-comp`, you usually get a message similar to `no-zlib-dynamic`. I don't see that, so I believe you are getting what you expect.

> however, when I compile Zlib does not appear as a dependency inside library.

Can you provide the output `dumpbin` on the import tables or look for the dependency with something like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)?

---

Related: usually, you should try to avoid compression because it leaks information. So you usually configure with `no-comp`. I can only say "usually" because I don't know your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at OpenSSL source file c_zlib.c you will see:

```
/*
 * When OpenSSL is built on Windows, we do not want to require that
 * the ZLIB.DLL be available in order for the OpenSSL DLLs to
 * work.  Therefore, all ZLIB routines are loaded at run time
 * and we do not link to a .LIB file when ZLIB_SHARED is set.
 */
```

and code below this lines:

```
  zlib_dso = DSO_load(NULL, "ZLIB1", NULL, 0);
  p_compress = (compress_ft) DSO_bind_func(zlib_dso, "compress"); 
  p_inflate = (inflate_ft) DSO_bind_func(zlib_dso, "inflate"); 
  ...
```

So, zlib1.dll will be loaded and binded dynamically by this code and so you can't see static linkage to zlib1.dll in libeay32.dll.

In others words, all will work finely :)